# How to convert a method from C# to JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Hi I have written a method that returns a string. Now i want to convert the below method to jquery with the same parameters. Can any one help me on this. Below is my method

```
public String GetNthWeekdayOfMonth(DateTime EnteredDate, int Number, DayOfWeek weekday)
{
     String error = "";
     var days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(EnteredDate.Year, EnteredDate.Month)).Select(day => new DateTime(EnteredDate.Year, EnteredDate.Month, day));
     var weekdays = from day in days
                    where day.DayOfWeek == weekday
                    orderby day.Day ascending
                    select day;
     int index = Number - 1;
     if (index >= 0 && index < weekdays.Count())
         return Convert.ToString(weekdays.ElementAt(index));
     else
         error = "The specified day does not exist in this ";
     return error;
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Is this C#? Did you want to create a web-service to be called from JavaScript ?

Comment: You have no DOM manipulation or HTTP requests going on here so why do you want to involve jQuery?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. If you want to convert a function to JavaScript, then learn enough JavaScript to make a reasonable attempt first.

Comment: You know jQuery is not a language but a javascript library/framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exact answer but can be helpful

http://sharpkit.net/Live.aspx

this is c# to javascript compiler and generate jquery and javascript code from c# code.

Comment: I am new to jquery so i  am asking a help from experts like you who are familiar in jquery. Yes this is  a c# method